# Do these jvmFlags specify that the heap should never exceed 256MB or that it should be at least 256MB?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, maven-2, heap-memory

Regarding the following jvm flags below:

```
                    <jvmFlag>-Xms256M</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Xmx256M</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</jvmFlag>
```

Do they represent a minimum or a maximum heap of 256MB?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.gae.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmFlags>
                    <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Xms256M</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Xmx256M</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Dmail.log_mail_level=WARNING</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Dmail.log_mail_body=true</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags>
                <severity>0</severity>
                <serverId>${google.app.id}</serverId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                    <version>${gae.runtime}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies> 
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

`-Xms` specifies the *initial* (or minimum) size of the heap.
`-Xmx` specifies the *maximum* size of the heap.

In this combination the specify that the heap should be *exactly* 256 MB.

Comment: Note that the MaxPermSize is also 256 MB, but that is different than the heap.  That is space that is allocated for things like classes that have been loaded.  It's space is separate, so your application (potentially) use up to 512 MB with these settings.

Answer (score 0):

The **-Xms** is the starting size for the heap.
The **-Xmx** is the maximum size for the heap.

This means that **-Xms256M** and **-Xmx256M** will give a heap of 256MB that is not allowed to expand.

However, keep in mind that this does *not* include other memory structures that the JVM will allocate, and so the overall usage may exceed this.